# Does D'Fusion for Unity support Android deployment?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I know D'Fusion Mobile supports Android deployment but [Total Immersion's technical page on D'Fusion for Unity](http://www.t-immersion.com/products/dfusion-unity/dfusion-unity) doesn't say anything about Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 9/3/13, D'Fusion Unity plugin doesn't support Android.